# How can I fix variables of an array of objects being undefined when being imported from a json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am creating a website to practice my coding on and I came across a problem while doing so. I am trying to import data from a json file with a forloop and the variables came back as undefined. I think it has to do with the i variable in the foreach, but I could be wrong. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('package.json', function(data){
        for(var i in data)
        {
            var username = i.username;
            var value = i.value;
            var tokens= i.tokens;
            $(".list-group").append('<li>' + username + ' has deposited $' + value + ' in ' + tokens + ' tokens</li>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is a copy of the json file

```
{
  "u1":
  {
    "username": "Username1",
    "tokens": 2,
    "value": 26
  },
  "u2":
  {
    "username": "Username2",
    "tokens": 4,
    "value": 292
  },
  "u3":
  {
    "username": "Username3",
    "tokens": 10,
    "value": 127
  },
  "u4":
  {
    "username": "Username4",
    "tokens": 3,
    "value": 12
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting a copy of the JSON will help

Comment: I think you're right, it has something to do with the `i`, as it's really the objects key, most likely a string, and you should be doing `data[i].username`

Comment: @adeneo: *Always* a string, with `for-in`. :-)

Comment: @ NightShadows: If `data` is an array, probably best not to use `for-in` on it, as that's not what `for-in` is for. Use `forEach` or jQuery's `$.each` or a simple `for` loop or [any of several other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 3):

if `data` is an array, `i` will be an Integer-value string of the *index*.

You'll want `data[i].username`, `data[i].value`, `data[i].tokens` instead

---

if `data` is an object, you don't need to iterate through it

You'll want `data.username`, `data.value`, `data.tokens` instead

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the technical clarification <3

Answer (score 0):

if the data from json is array of object use it;

```
    <script>
            $.getJSON('package.json', function(data){
                for(var i in data)
                {
                    var username = data[i].username;
                    var value = data[i].value;
                    var tokens= data[i].tokens;
                    $(".list-group").append('<li>' + username + ' has deposited $' + value + ' in ' + tokens + ' tokens</li>');
                }
            });
</script>
```

else  use it

```
 <script>
            $.getJSON('package.json', function(data){

                    var username = data.username;
                    var value = data.value;
                    var tokens= data.tokens;
                    $(".list-group").append('<li>' + username + ' has deposited $' + value + ' in ' + tokens + ' tokens</li>');

            });
</script>
```